# how to display dropdown menu correctly

Tags: html, css

I want to dsiplay menu when hover but not working.

HTML code pour afficher:

```
<nav>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
        <li class="current">other</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="index-2.html">services</a>
            <ul class="drop">
                <li><a href="index-2.html">s1</a></li>
                <li><a href="index-4.html">s2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS code to display menu and drop:

```
nav .menu li:hover > a {
    background: #e2782e;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    color: white;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.drop{
    display:none;
}

li :hover > .drop{
    display:black;
}
```

Comment: Display:black -> display:block

Answer (score 1):

Please check below code for your reference.

```css
ul.drop{display:none;}
nav ul li a:hover{background:#ccc;}
nav ul li:hover ul.drop{display:block;}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">other</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">services</a>
      <ul class="drop">
        <li><a href="#">s1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">s2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav>


  <ul class="menu">


                                    <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
                                    <li class="current">other</a></li>


                                    <li>
                                        <a href="index-2.html">services</a>
                                      <ul class="drop">

                                    <li><a href="index-2.html">s1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index-4.html">s2</a></li>

                                      </ul>
                                    </li>

                                </ul>

  </ul>

</nav>


nav .menu li:hover .drop li a {
  background: #e2782e;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  color: white;
  font-weight:bold;
}

.drop{
    display:none;
}

li :hover  > .drop{
    display:block;
}

Please try this code.
```

Comment: Please add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Several issues:

- unnested `</a>` tag for "other" menu item.
- extraneous `</ul>` tag at the end
- `black` is not a valid value for the `display` property, use `list-item` instead.

Edit: see Nick De Jaeger's answer above for the corrected code. Using `display: block` also works, but `list-item` is more appropriate in this case (`<li>`).

Answer (score 0):

Bart look here this is all css when I hover on drop all auther menu item hided

```
nav .menu {
      height: 60px;
      background: #8d8989;
      border-radius: 5px;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      text-align: center; /* center the li */

    }

    nav .menu li {
      display: inline-block; 
    }

    nav .menu li a{
      font-family: arial, sans-serif;
      color: #fff;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      line-height: 60px;
        font-weight:bold;
      vertical-align: middle;
      padding: 20px;
      transition: all 0.5s;
    }
    nav .menu li:hover > a {
      background: #e2782e;
      transition: all 0.5s;
      color: #FFF;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    .drop{
        display: none;
    }

    li:hover > .drop{
     display: list-item;
        background-color:red;
    }
```

html

```
 <nav>


  <ul class="menu">


                                    <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.html">contact</a></li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="index-2.html"><?php echo $lang['MENU_OUR_PRODUCTS']; ?></a>
                                      <ul class="drop">

                                    <li><a href="index-2.html"><?php echo $lang['MENU_History']; ?></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index-4.html"><?php echo $lang['MENU_CONTACT_US']; ?></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index-2.html"><?php echo $lang['MENU_History']; ?></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index-4.html"><?php echo $lang['MENU_CONTACT_US']; ?></a></li>
                                      </ul>
                                    </li>

                                </ul>

  </ul>

</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

see here **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sodnt73q/)**

you have some problems in your code

**first in your HTML** you have a closing tag `</a>` on the `li.current` but you don't have any `<a>` there. so that closing tag is not required

also you have and extra closing tag `</ul>` , you have only 2 `ul` to close , `ul.menu` and `ul.drop` so you need only 2 `</ul>` not 3.

**second in your CSS** , you have a space between `li` and `:hover` , you need to write them together like `li:hover` .

also `display:black` doesn't exist, i guess you wanted to write `display:block`

Updated code HTML :

```
 <ul class="menu">


                                <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
                                <li class="current">other</li>


                                <li>
                                    <a href="index-2.html">services</a>
                                  <ul class="drop">

                                <li><a href="index-2.html">s1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="index-4.html">s2</a></li>

                                  </ul>
                                </li>



  </ul>
```

CSS :

```
nav .menu li:hover > a {
  background: #e2782e;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  color: white;
  font-weight:bold;
}

.drop{
    display:none;
}

li:hover  > .drop{
    display:block;
}
```

let me know if it helps.

*NOTE : there are so many questions about this on stackoverflow, you should be able to find your answer very quickly , also you might want to check this **[CSS Dropdowns](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp)***

Answer (score -1):

```css
nav .menu li:hover > a {
  background: #e2782e;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.drop{
    display: none;
}

li:hover > .drop{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
    <li class="current"><a href="#">other</a></li>
    <li><a href="index-2.html">services</a>
      <ul class="drop">
        <li><a href="index-2.html">s1</a></li>
        <li><a href="index-4.html">s2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: The items are all on a different line. Do you have any additional css (e.g. specifying the width)? Try using `display: list-item` instead.